# boolean list reset

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there a way to reset the below list back to all 'False' I have a program that uses a boolean list e.g.

```
bat=[False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False]
```

When the main loop does it's second iteration for the second team it still carries the 'True' values from the first team. I need to clear it up so the second team can record correct scores.

Any help will be much appreciated. Cheers

Comment: What's wrong with `for i in range(len(bat)): bat[i] = False`?

Comment: @FerdinandBeyer: that it takes too much typing? :)

Comment: @larsmans: Yes but that's a poor excuse in my opinion :)

Answer (score 4):

Why not just rebind the variable before each iteration? I.e.,

```
for team in teams:
    bat = [False] * 11
    # do whatever
```

If you must reset the list in-place, that's

```
bat[:] = [False] * 11
```

or

```
bat[:] = [False] * len(bat)
```

Comment: Could you explain why to use `bat[:] =` instead of `bat =` here?  Thanks!

Comment: @mVChr: `bat[:]` changes the list in-place. If you have other references to the same list, they will get changed along with `bat`. Try printing `a` and `b` after `a=[0]; b=a; a[:]=[]`. Now try the same without the `[:]`.

Answer (score 1):

A simple list comprehension should do the trick:

```
bat = [False for _ in bat]
```

Or multiply by `len`:

```
bat = [False] * len(bat)
```

**EDIT:** You should use `bat[:] =` for these assignments (see comments on larsmans' answer for why)

Comment: Why *should* you use `bat[:]`?  The OP seems to only have one reference of `bat` that needs to be reset before each iteration, so it is just valid for the current iteration.  Since you already build a temporary list, modifying the original in-place is just (tiny) overkill.